# Django query not passing to AJAX in JSON Format

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, forms

I'm trying to simply fill a textfield with its corresponding database value using Django and AJAX. The goal is that when the dropdown value is changed the textfield auto-updates. I get the following error in console:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 3 & Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: data is not defined

I have tried doing it without the JSON but then the data turns out to be the whole html code of the currently loaded page.

**tasks.html**

```
<form method="POST" id="function" function-url="{% url 'synctool:load_function' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Execute</button>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $("#id_function_name").change(
                            function () 
                                {
                                    var url = $("#function").attr("function-url");
                                    var function_id = $(this).val(); 
                                    console.log(function_id)

                                    $.ajax(
                                    {
                                        url: url,
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        data: 
                                        {
                                            'function_name': function_id
                                        },
                                        success: function (data)
                                        {   
                                            console.log('success')

                                            $("#id_script_location").val(data);
                                        },
                                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                                        {
                                        console.log('jqXHR:');
                                        console.log(jqXHR);
                                        console.log('textStatus:');
                                        console.log(textStatus);
                                        console.log('errorThrown:');
                                        console.log(errorThrown);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    console.log("ajax executed")

                                });
</script>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.load_script, name='load_function'),
```

**views.py**

```
def load_script(request):

    function_id = request.GET.get('function_name')
    query = serialize('json', Task.objects.filter(function_name_id = function_id).values(), cls=LazyEncoder)

    return query
```

Comment: Why exactly you need that being a JSON? It's just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Django querysets and JSON dont really match. I was able to find the solution myself. The final code:

**views.py**

```
# Dynamic Load/Ajax
def load_script(request):

    function_id = request.GET.get('function_name')
    query = Task.objects.filter(function_name_id = function_id).values_list('script_location', flat=True).first()

    return HttpResponse(query)
```

**tasks.html**

```
<!-- JQuery Ajax script -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$("#id_function_name").change(
                            function () 
                                {
                                    var url = $("#function").attr("function-url");
                                    var function_id = $(this).val(); 

                                    $.ajax(
                                    {
                                        url: url,
                                        data: { 'function_name': function_id },
                                        success: function (data)
                                        {   
                                            console.log('ajax load success')

                                            $("#id_script_location").val(data);
                                        },
                                        error: function() 
                                        {
                                        console.log('ajax load error');

                                        }
                                    });                                                                  
                                });
</script>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^load_function/$', views.load_script, name='load_function'),
```

Answer (score 0):

### views.py

```
import json 

        def load_script(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                response_json = request.POST
                response_json = json.dumps(response_json)
                data = json.loads(response_json)
                query = data['function_name']
                data ={'query': query}
                return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

### and in js

```
    var patch = {'function_name': function_id}

      $.ajax(
                                        {
                                            url: url,
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            data: 
                                             patch,
                                            success: function (data)
                                            {   
                                                console.log('success')

                                                $("#id_script_location").val(data);
                                            },
                                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                                            {
                                            console.log('jqXHR:');
                                            console.log(jqXHR);
                                            console.log('textStatus:');
                                            console.log(textStatus);
                                            console.log('errorThrown:');
                                            console.log(errorThrown);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        console.log("ajax executed")

                                    });
```